# Mutual recursion with computation expressions

Tags: f#

Currently I have the following structure:

```
let rec foo x = State.state{
    let rec bar =
        //...
        foo 5
        //...
    //...
    bar
    //...
}
```

I would like to extract the 'bar' function and obtain a structure such as:

```
let rec foo x = State.state{
    //...
    bar
    //...
}
and bar =  State.state{
    //...
    foo 5
    //...
}
```

This would allow me to have another function foo2 that could also use bar and avoid code duplication.

The question is: my proposal does not compile in F# and apparently that is because of the State context. So what is the syntactically correct way to reach the desired code structure?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
let rec foo x = 
  async {
    return! bar x
  }
and bar x = 
  async {
    if x = 0
      then printfn "bar"
      else do! foo (x - 1) 
  }
Async.RunSynchronously (foo 10)
```

I had problems with the formatting first so make sure your indentations are correct and that your exclamation marks are at the right place, otherwise the type won't work out.

Comment: Indeed formatting my state computations as you did with async, solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Friedrich Gretz, If the answer solved your question, accept it

Comment: @FoggyFinder not sure whether your comment was meant to be helpful or nagging but in any case there is certain delay of time imposed by stackoverflow before you are allowed to mark a solution as such. Which I have done now.